# Read external properties file from jar added to an unpacked WAR deployed under Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

I'm trying to access a simple **.properties** file from a JAR that is added to an unpacked **.war** file in Apache Tomcat. This is the approach I tried so far:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../classes/testProps.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(inputStream);
System.out.println(props.get("test"));
```

But this doesn't do the trick as I keep getting a `null` on the inputStream.

For context, I need to put the properties file under the **WEB-INF/classes** folder and the jar file in **WEB-INF/lib**.

Comment: Have you looked at ServletContext.getResource()?

Comment: Try `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("testProps.properties")`. The `classes` directory is already on the class path, so the resource name should be relative to that.

Comment: It doesn't work, still getting a NullPointerException. I even tried to restart the web container.